# Video not playing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, assets

I'm having trouble loading a video into my view in Rails. I'm using the video_tag helper like so:

`<%= video_tag "BigBuckBunny.mp4", :size => "600x400", :controls => true %>`

I have my application.rb file configured like so:

`config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"`

See: [HTML5 VIDEO is not working in my rails 3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857262/html5-video-is-not-working-in-my-rails-3-app)

The video file is located under 'app/assets/videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4'. The video file seems to be loading because I'm no longer getting a 404 error, but I still can't get the video to play.

[Console showing correct asset loaded in Rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBF5f.png)

Comment: Have you restarted your server? I just did the same thing with a test mp4 and it worked fine.

Comment: Also, are the video container and controls visible to you? Is possible you just have it inside of an element that isn't visible.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by replacing the video_tag with the corresponding HTML tags. I'm going to quote directly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674399/uri-mismatch-rails-generates-md5-digest-in-asset-url-in-production-but-controll):

```
<video width="600" height="400" control="controls">
    <source src="../../../public/videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Except in my code that still didn't work. I ended up using this:

```
<video width="600" height="400" control="controls">
    <source src="../../../assets/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```